# UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not a subtype - error

Tags: hibernate, jodatime, usertype

I am using Usercore 3.0.0 Ga and Spi 3.0.0 libraries but I am getting this error.

```
UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not a subtype
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not a subtype
java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:339)
org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:57)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
classes.session.SessionCreate.buildSessionFactory1(SessionCreate.java:17)
classes.session.SessionCreate.<clinit>(SessionCreate.java:9)
classes.creatorclasses.CreateBranchMaster.register(CreateBranchMaster.java:14)
org.apache.jsp.ResultJspProc.CreateBranch_jsp._jspService(CreateBranch_jsp.java:132)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am facing this error from long please help..

thanks,
Abhijeet.